# Trouble in retrieving table names from Android SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to insert tables in Android SQLite database and then want to show that table names in a listView but after creating tables in database I am unable to retrieve table names from database.

My code of retrieving table names is as follows:

```
public void updateBranchList()
{
    //this method will open database
    openDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_temp_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql,null);
    //branchList is an ArrayList<String>
    branchList.clear();

    if(c.moveToFirst())
        while(!c.isAfterLast())
        {
            String s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            branchList.add(s);
            c.moveToNext();
        }
    db.close();
}

public void openDatabase()
{
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("studentinfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sqlite_temp_master` table contains information about tables in the temporary database. For information about tables in the main database, you have to use `sqlite_master` instead.

Comment: i have tried sqlite_master also that is also not working

Comment: Sorry sqlite_master is working there was some error in my Sql query Thanks